# Finding the line of intersection of two planes

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

This is a problem on my homework (so please do not provide more than hints as I definitely don't want you to do it for me). I'm just stuck and was hoping someone might point out my mistake or suggest I do something different.

> The problem says I need to find the line of intersection of the two
>   planes as follows: \begin{align}
>  P_1:3z-\left(3x+y\right)=-14,\:\:P_2:2y-4x+4z=-12. \end{align}

I first distributed the negative through on $P_1$ to get
\begin{align}
3z-3x-y=-14,\tag{1}
\end{align}
but now my textbook says that the normal vector to this plane $P_1$ and $P_2$ should be the numbers in front of the $x,y,z$, which would give me the two vectors
\begin{align}
\vec{v}_1=\left\langle 3,-3,1 \right\rangle,\:\vec{v}_2=\left\langle 2,-4,4 \right\rangle,\tag{2}
\end{align}
but that is not the case when I graph them (unless somehow I'm graphing them wrong, but I don't see how that's possible...). And when I take the cross product of these two vectors (which I've also checked) I get
\begin{align}
\vec{v}_1\times \vec{v}_2=\left\langle -16,-14,-6 \right\rangle,\tag{3}
\end{align}
and this I know to be right, but it isn't at all a scalar multiple of the line of intersection somehow.

Comment: $v_1 = [-3, -1, 3], v_2 = [-4, 2, 4]$.

Comment: @Kaster How is it that I have the normal vectors wrong? Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The normal vector to the plane $ax + by + cz = d$ is $\langle a, b, c\rangle$. Note that $3$, the first component of $v_1$, is not the coefficient of $x$ but rather the coefficient of $z$.

Comment: Oh my...that's a bad oversight on my part :P Thank you so much!

Comment: I'll mark it as the right answer in a few minutes when I can...

Comment: Ha 2 minutes left before I can mark it as the right answer, but thanks :) I got it right. I'm so embarassed haha I can't believe I couldn't figure that out.